# TensorFlow Lite interpreter initialization causing app crash

Tags: android, kotlin, artificial-intelligence, classification, tensorflow-lite

I am working on an Android app that performs classification using a trained TensorFlow Lite model. The model has been loaded using the getModelByteBuffer function, and the input features are being classified using the loaded model. However, when I try to initialize the TensorFlow Lite interpreter using the loaded model, the app crashes. The app crashes with no specific error message when this code is executed. I have tried looking for solutions online, but I haven't been able to find any that work.

Can anyone help me identify the cause of the app crash and suggest a possible solution?it for a uni project i would be extermely gratful if any of you would help me Thank you.

the log that i wrote after initializing the interpreter is not displaying so i think the problem is around there
Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
private fun classification(uid: String) {
        val password = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.passET)
        val mdw =  moyenne(dwelltime)
        val mft2= moyenne(flight_time2)
        val mft3= moyenne(flight_time3)
        val Moyenne = arrayListOf(mdw,mft2,mft3)
        Log.d("tflite", "interpreter before initilizing ")
      
            tflite = Interpreter(getModelByteBuffer())
        Log.d("tflite", "interpreter afterinitilizing ")
        try {
            val input = getInputTensor(Moyenne)
            val output = Array(1) { LongArray(NUM_CLASSES) }
            tflite?.run(input, output)

            // Get predicted class index
            val predictedClassIndex = output[0].indices.maxByOrNull { output[0][it] } ?: -1

            val predictedClassName = getClassNames()[predictedClassIndex]

            store.collection("users").document(uid).get().addOnSuccessListener {user->
                val nom = user.getString("nom")
                if (predictedClassName == nom){
                    startActivity(Intent(this, Activity_expert::class.java))
                }else{
                    password.error = "Try Again"
                    password.text = null
                    tentative++
                    onResume()
                    if (tentative==3){
                        store.collection("users").document(uid).update("blacklist",true)
                        warning.blacklist(uid)
                        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        builder.setMessage("you are blocked !!!")
                        builder.setNeutralButton("ok",{ dialogInterface: DialogInterface, i: Int ->
                            finish()
                        })
                        builder.show()

                    }
                    warning.dynamic(nom, predictedClassName, algo!!)
                }
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.d("tflite", "error")
                Log.e("tflite", "Exception caught: ${e.message}")
        }
```

i tried upgrading my tensorflow lite depedencies in the the gradle app file but no luck

Comment: Usually when the app crashes there will be a log with tag "FATAL", search for this one on logcat and then add it to you question, otherwise it would be almost impossible to debug this without the complete app